# Swift for ios7 or lower platforms

Tags: ios, swift

Would it be possible to use Swift and also create apps for iOS5,6,7 compatible apps? The thing here is that Swift only works with XCode6 and the new LLVM and I'm not sure if those apps will only work for iOS8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that LLVM will compile for iOS 7 and up. They did confirm that it would not be compatible with iOS 6.